# Removing outliers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database with a table like the following:

```
ID      |  temp_ext   
1          8                
2          8.5                        
3          8.7                                          
4          25                           
5          9

6          10.2                
7          17                        
8          17.8                                          
9          11                          
10         13
```

I want to remove the outliers as follows:

1. Look at a temp_ext value.
2. Compare to previous id's temp_ext value.
3. If it is greater than 5 more than the previous temp_ext value, make it equal to the previous temp_ext value.
4. Repeat

For the example we would finally have:

```
    ID      |  temp_ext   
    1          8                
    2          8.5                        
    3          8.7                                          
    4          8.7                          
    5          9    
    6          10.2                
    7          10.2                        
    8          10.2                                          
    9          11                          
    10         13
```

Answer (score 2):

There must be a set-based way to do this, but I can't see any non-convoluted way to do that.  Perhaps someone else will come up with a better way.

I've built a test rig that uses a cursor to fix the table where it needs to be fixed.

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Outliers') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Outliers;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Outliers
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , temp_ext decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Outliers (temp_ext)
VALUES (8)
    , (8.5)
    , (8.7)
    , (25)
    , (9)
    , (10.2)
    , (17)
    , (17.8)
    , (11)
    , (13);

DECLARE @ID int;
DECLARE @temp_ext DECIMAL(10,2);
DECLARE @prior_temp_ext DECIMAL(10,2);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
FOR
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Outliers o
ORDER BY o.ID;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @temp_ext
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @temp_ext - @prior_temp_ext > 5
    BEGIN
        SET @temp_ext = @prior_temp_ext
        UPDATE dbo.Outliers
        SET temp_ext = @temp_ext
        WHERE ID = @ID;
    END
    ELSE
        SET @prior_temp_ext = @temp_ext;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @temp_ext
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Selecting from the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Outliers;
```

Shows these rows:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | temp_ext |
+----+----------+
|  1 |     8.00 |
|  2 |     8.50 |
|  3 |     8.70 |
|  4 |     8.70 |
|  5 |     9.00 |
|  6 |    10.20 |
|  7 |    10.20 |
|  8 |    10.20 |
|  9 |    11.00 |
| 10 |    13.00 |
+----+----------+
```

As mentioned by @Ypercube in a comment, you could do the update as a single statement after the cursor completes, like:

```
DECLARE @ID int;
DECLARE @temp_ext DECIMAL(10,2);
DECLARE @prior_temp_ext DECIMAL(10,2);
DECLARE @RowsToChange TABLE (
    ID int NOT NULL
    , temp_ext decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
FOR
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Outliers o
ORDER BY o.ID;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @temp_ext
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @temp_ext - @prior_temp_ext > 5
    BEGIN
        SET @temp_ext = @prior_temp_ext
        INSERT INTO @RowsToChange (ID, temp_ext)
        VALUES (@ID, @temp_ext);
    END
    ELSE
        SET @prior_temp_ext = @temp_ext;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @temp_ext
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT o.*
        , NewTempExt = rtc.temp_ext
    FROM dbo.Outliers o
        INNER JOIN @RowsToChange rtc ON o.ID = rtc.ID
)
UPDATE cte
SET cte.temp_ext = cte.NewTempExt;
```

The tendency here is to think the `INSERT INTO @RowsToChange` will be only in-memory, however even table variables are backed by a temporary table stored in tempdb; so this *may* result in more overall work.  Depending on the number of rows in the table, and the number of rows that need to be updated; it may or may not be better to use the second method.  I would also try wrapping the first method in an explicit transaction.

Comment: Nice. A variation would be to keep in the cursor only the rows that need updating and update them all in one statement in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use @@rowcount, we can rely on set operation to accomplish this work (I borrowed Max Vernon's data preparation code in my following code, thx @Max)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Outliers') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Outliers;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Outliers
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , temp_ext decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Outliers (temp_ext)
VALUES (8)
    , (8.5)
    , (8.7)
    , (25)
    , (9)
    , (10.2)
    , (17)
    , (17.8)
    , (11)
    , (13);
go

declare @i int = 1;

while (@i > 0)
begin
  update o2 
  set o2.temp_ext = o.temp_ext
  from dbo.outliers o2
  inner join dbo.outliers o
  on o.id = o2.id - 1
  where o2.temp_ext > o.temp_ext + 5;
  set @i = @@rowcount;
  print 'update once ...'
end
```

Then select * from dbo.Outliers will return the exact result as shown below.
By using print 'update once', we can see how many updates are run to achieve the goal, in this case, 3 times, this reduces the loop times compared with cursor version.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In practice, looping the update statement may be a sufficient answer. However, I considered the possibility of a worst case scenario, where every record was 6 greater than the previous. The loop would update all but the first record the firs time through, all but the first two the second time through, and so on.

I also considered what happened with a notably larger data set.

I tested the cursor, the update loop, and the option below with 10,000 records: both with the above ten records, repeated (in the same order shown) 1,000 times, and with 10,000 records, where the temp_ext value of the first record was 8, and each successive record was 6 more than the previous.

My solution requires three steps:

1. Identify all rows where the following row has a value more than 5 greater than the current row.
2. For each of those rows, identify the lowest-numbered row where the value is not 5 greater than the current row. All rows from the one above the current row, through the one below this row, should be changed.
3. Again, for each of those rows, eliminate any where one of the other rows would include the current row in its update set.

Here's the code, with the repeated copies of the ten rows originally provided:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Outliers') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Outliers;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Outliers
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , temp_ext decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @insertCount int = 0;

WHILE (@insertCount < 1000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Outliers (temp_ext)
    VALUES (8)
        , (8.5)
        , (8.7)
        , (25)
        , (9)
        , (10.2)
        , (17)
        , (17.8)
        , (11)
        , (13);
    SET @insertCount += 1;
END;

DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE()
;

DECLARE @max_id int;
SELECT @max_id = MAX(ID) from dbo.Outliers;

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#to_change') IS NOT NULL) 
DROP TABLE #to_change;
CREATE TABLE #to_change (OK_ID int PRIMARY KEY, temp_ext decimal(10,2), Max_Outlier_ID int);


-- Get IDs for all rows where the next row is an outlier; at the minimum,
--   those next rows must all be reset to our current row.
INSERT INTO #to_change (OK_ID, temp_ext, Max_Outlier_ID)
SELECT cur.ID, cur.temp_ext, @max_id
  FROM dbo.Outliers cur
         INNER JOIN dbo.Outliers nxt ON (cur.ID + 1 = nxt.ID)
 WHERE cur.temp_ext + 5 < nxt.temp_ext
;

-- For all rows where the next row is an outlier, find the next row after that
--   that is *not* an outlier.
-- All rows from the row after our "OK" row, through the row before our
--   "next OK" row, are outliers, and should be set to the value of the "OK"
--   row.
-- NOTE: If all rows after the current row are outliers, we won't find a
--   next OK row. That's why we default that to the max ID initially.
UPDATE t
   SET t.Max_Outlier_ID = z.next_OK_ID - 1
  FROM #to_change t
         INNER JOIN (SELECT c.OK_ID, MIN(o.ID) as next_OK_ID
                       FROM #to_change c
                              INNER JOIN dbo.Outliers o ON (c.OK_ID < o.ID AND c.temp_ext + 5 >= o.temp_ext)
                      GROUP BY c.OK_ID
                    ) z ON t.OK_ID = z.OK_ID
;

-- If an "OK" ID is in another "OK" ID's list of rows to update, 
--   drop it from the list; it's not really an "OK" row.
DELETE t
  FROM #to_change t
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM #to_change
                WHERE OK_ID < t.OK_ID
                  AND t.OK_ID <= Max_Outlier_ID
              )
;

-- Using our list of OK rows, and the rows to change based on them,
--   update the outliers.
UPDATE o
   SET temp_ext = t.temp_ext
  FROM dbo.Outliers o
         INNER JOIN #to_change t ON (o.ID BETWEEN t.OK_ID + 1 AND t.Max_Outlier_ID)
;

SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @now, GETDATE()) as [Run time (ms)];

SELECT * FROM dbo.Outliers;
```

The repeated update version, with this data set, completed in 0.1 to 0.2 seconds.  This version, with this data set, completed in 1.3 to 1.7 seconds.

However, with the following data set instead:

```
DECLARE @insertCount int = 0;
DECLARE @insertVal int = 8;
DECLARE @increment int = 6;

WHILE (@insertCount < 10000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Outliers (temp_ext) VALUES (@insertVal);
    SET @insertCount += 1;
    SET @insertVal += @increment;
END;
```

With the repeating UPDATE version of the code, this takes roughly 7 minutes and 50 seconds. With the three step process I've posted, it takes 2-3 seconds.

Again, the likelihood of **every** row needing to be reset to the first row's value, in any real data, is small. However, for larger data sets, I would think it would only take a run of 10-20 rows that all need to be reset to same row for the three-step process to be looking better. At a minimum, it's more predictable.